# Why isn't this Java jar working?

Tags: java, runtime

When I run the code below I get the following error.

```
C:\Documents and Settings\BOS\Desktop\test>java -jar test.jar
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
        at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.getMainClassFromJar(Unknown Source)
        at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(Unknown Source)
```

I've got these files in \test directory = crimson.jar robosuite-api.jar and test.jar.

Here is the example they give to launch a robot?

```
import com.kapowtech.robosuite.api.java.rql.*;
public class SimpleRunRobot {
public static void main(String[] args) {
if (args.length < 1) {
System.out.println("Usage: RunRobot <robotURL>");
System.exit(1);
}
try {
// Run the robot
RQLResult result =
RobotExecutor.getRobotExecutor().execute(args[0]);
// Output the results
System.out.println(result);
}
catch (RQLException e) {
System.out.println("An error occurred: " + e);
}
}
}
```

Why is this giving me that Unknown Source error?

```
 package robosuite.robots;

    import com.kapowtech.robosuite.api.java.rql.RQLException;
    import com.kapowtech.robosuite.api.java.rql.RQLResult;
    import com.kapowtech.robosuite.api.java.rql.RobotExecutor;
    import com.kapowtech.robosuite.api.java.rql.construct.RQLObjects;


    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.List;



       /**
         * 
         * <p>
         * This is an autogenerated class. It has been generated from the
         * <code>library:/test.robot</code> file.
         *
         * @author RoboSuite
         */
    public class Test {

        // ----------------------------------------------------------------------
        // Class fields
        // ----------------------------------------------------------------------

        private static final String ROBOT_URL = "library:/test.robot";
        private static final RobotExecutor ROBOT_EXECUTOR = RobotExecutor.getRobotExecutor(SingletonRQLEngine.getInstance());
        private static final Converter CONVERTER = Converter.getInstance();



  // ----------------------------------------------------------------------
    // Constructors
    // ----------------------------------------------------------------------

    /**
     * Creates a new Test instance that can be used to execute the
     * <code>library:/test.robot</code>.
     */
        public Test() {
        }

        // ----------------------------------------------------------------------
        // Instance methods
        // ----------------------------------------------------------------------

        /**
         * Executes this robot.
         * 
         * @param test an input object to the robot. 
         * @return an array of output objects.
         * @throws java.io.IOException if the execution fails for some reason.
         */
        public Testst[] run(Test0 test) throws java.io.IOException {
            try {
                // Prepare input objects
                List parameters = new ArrayList();
                parameters.add(test);

                RQLObjects inputObjects = CONVERTER.convertBeansToRQLObjects(parameters);

                // Run robot
                RQLResult rqlResult = ROBOT_EXECUTOR.execute(ROBOT_URL, inputObjects);

                // Extract output objects
                RQLObjects outputObjects = rqlResult.getOutputObjects();
                List result = CONVERTER.convertRQLObjectsToBeans(outputObjects);
                return (Testst[]) result.toArray(new Testst[result.size()]);
            } catch (RQLException e) {
                throw new IOException(e.toString());
            }
        }


        /* ------------------------------------------------------------------- */
    }
```

Comment: What is the content of the manifest file?  Is that the entire stack trace?  It usually indicates a line number.

Comment: I'm a python guy - any clue where to look for a manifest file?

Comment: AVD - How do I know what location to find the other needed Class Paths?

Comment: ^ did this Result =  getting the original exception.  What code do you want to see?

Comment: @AVD `-cp` is ignored when `-jar` is specified.  It is necessary to add references to the dependent Jars in the manifest, if using the `-jar` option.

Comment: @JKD Java - version = 1.7.0_01

Comment: I had to break up the script since it wouldn't let me post the whole thing without more moments - feature request j/k

Comment: @chavenor - Where is main - entry point method? It is not possible to launch JAR without having entry point.

Comment: @AVD You don't see that entry point in the source code above?  -- Man I wish I new more about Java.

Comment: @AVD i added the core example they gave in some documentation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
java -cp test.jar
```

include your other .jar files also

If you are using a manifest file make sure you have defined your main class.
for e.g.

```
Main-Class: test.MyApp
```

Comment: How do I know what to put for the Main-Class?

Comment: If you know the class which has the Main Method ("Public static void main") you put that. if not try java -cp .;crimson.jar;robosuite-api.jar -jar test.jar

Comment: if not try java -cp .;crimson.jar;robosuite-api.jar;test.jar

Answer (score 1):

If your using Java 7, Read this.

https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=7067922

Answer (score 0):

You have to add the name of the class having main() method in META-INF/manifest file.

Here is the link with more information : 
http://java.sun.com/developer/Books/javaprogramming/JAR/basics/manifest.html

Thanks.

Comment: If the Jar lacked a manifest that specified main, it would give a different error.

Comment: Do you think that the newer versions of Java could be throwing this script off?

Comment: I think Java 7 is not quite shippable at the moment.  I installed it and when it would not run a variety of projects I work on, uninstalled it.  Try it with Java 6.

Comment: @AVD  I'll take your word for it, but that is an odd error message for 'no main class specified'.

Comment: @AndrewThompson - according to the bug report linked above, this is fixed in 7u2(b02).  But you are correct about Java 7.  Indeed, even Oracle's "http://java.com" site does not recommend Java 7 for end users at the moment; see http://java.com/en/download/faq/java7.xml.

Comment: @AdnrewThompson - the version of have is 7 correct? Java installed (1.7.0_01).

Comment: @chavenor - upgrade to 1.7.0_02 if you want a fix for this JVM bug.  But really this bug is that the JVM is mishandling an error your JAR file.  And you'll have to fix the latter error anyway.

Answer (score 0):

> Why is this giving me that Unknown Source error?

The "unknown source" messages are not an error.  It is the JVM telling you that the code that you are executing was compiled without any debug information; e.g. with the `-gLnone` option.  As a result, the source file names and line numbers that would normally be included in the stacktrace are not available.

In this case, the code is some platform specific stuff that is internal to the JVM.  Don't worry about it ...